# Upnp device searching in Windows

Tags: upnp, ssdp

I have a question regarding UPnP API in Windows. IUPnPDeviceFinderCallback contains method SearchComplete. It's invoked when the framework notifies application that "initial search for network devices has been completed".

M-SEARCH packet contains MX key. During MX time network devices should send a response. How Windows decides that the search was completed? Does it add a constant time margin for MX time? I was studying other open source ssdp libraries but I didn't find library which provide such notification. All of them have implemented "device-added" "device-removed" or "device-updated" event.

Thanks in advance
K.

Comment: Without source it's impossible to tell but the logical assumption would be that SearchComplete will be invoked at the same that a corresponding synchronous find would return: This will probably be MX seconds (plus a little buffer) after the initial M-SEARCH was sent.